# How events are delivered in iOS apps?

Tags: ios

what does this image I got from apple developer tells us? what is the whole process after the user makes an interaction with the screen say a tap?

[image]

Comment: add link to the page from which you took this image.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html